# VSCode API: How to detect current launcher and event, when it's changed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, launch, launcher

While the extension is running, I need to know which launcher is the current one. In addition, I need to keep track of when the current launcher changes.

How to do it?

[image: image-2]

Comment: you can also run a launch with a command

Comment: I develop an extension, contained LSP server. And every time the launcher changing - the LSP logic must be reinitialized - without/before debugging.

Comment: if your extensions implements the launch type you know when it starts

Comment: Sure. But I need some important logic without/before debugging.